# Why is every word capitalized in a movie title?

Tags: title

All movie titles capital every word in them.

*Texas Chainsaw Massacre* and *Avengers: Infinity War* are a few examples.

My question is that why is it in this way?

Comment: Because titles are emphasised like that in the English language. That said, most movie titles are written in upper case. Certain letters might be emphasised, for instance, check out the posters for Lord of the Rings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not about movies, per se, but an English language convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several style guides that have slightly differing opinions on capitalisation in titles but most of them agree that most "significant" words should be capitalised in a  [title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case). These style guides are used in movies, TV, newspapers and online publications.

So, "*Avengers: Infinity War*" has every word capitalised, but "*Guardians of the Galaxy*" doesn't.

--- not related to movies

Then again, I worked for a publication where the style was to use sentence case even in a title (and only capitalise proper nouns, such as brand names).

Comment: "of" and "the" are never capitalized if they are at the middle of a pbrase. Unless it's needed.

Comment: True,most (if not all) style guides do agree on that, at least